# Setting up a LAN connection in Windows

Tags: windows-xp, connection, lan

I'm looking to set up a LAN connection under Windows XP.

What are the steps or instructions I should follow to make this work?

Comment: If you want to setup your internet connection then you should contact your ISP for more details

Comment: @trolle3000: that's almost as useful as *"have you tried turning it off and then on again?"*

Comment: @~quack, that is the easiest solution to many of life's problems

Comment: Edited by "Grammar Nazi" and still reads like this? Grammar Nazi, maybe you should rename yourself "Typo & Tag Nazi".

Comment: We need way much more info to help you out... Do you have a router, or the modem of your ISP is plugged straight into your computer? You need to edit you message to provide more infos please... We can't assume everything...

Comment: We're talking about LAN (local area network) so no ISP is involved.
We need more details about how many pc you want to connect and which kind of hardware you have (wifi, cabled, a switch etc etc)

Answer (score 1):

I think u want to connect 2 PCs. Let's assume so. Thus, you'll need to check this guide: 
[How To Create a LAN connection between 2 PCs](http://www.digitgeek.com/how-to-create-a-lan-connection-between-2-pcs/).

I kindly want to suggest you , to [search in Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20make%20lan%20connection) first, then check [related ones](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lan) within the site :)

Answer (score 0):

know how your network is set up. Assuming its a home system, there are a few basic setups people use. I'm NOT going into exotica like firewire networking

1. modem -> router -> system 
   The router can be a dedicated router, or a PC running ICS or a firewall. For the former, use standard ethernet cable from the modem to the router, and the router to the system.
2. modemrouter -> system 
   as above. just with the modem and router being one unit
3. modem -> system
   the simplest. Connect the modem to the system with ethernet or usb
4. lan -> system
   connect lan to system via ethernet. ensure that lan admin dosen't have you blocked off- say with mac filtering.

---

in all 3 cases run the network setup wizard. for 1 and 2 choose 'i connect through a gateway', for 3 select 'i connect directly to the internet'. Check if you have a connection from the network icon in control panel, or the ipconfig command.

For extra credit, you can use ICS to turn a system into a basic, moderately annoying to configure router.

Answer (score 0):

Basically connect the two computers together with a Category 5/5e/6 Ethernet cable. If both of the sides have their lights light up on the ports, then they are ready to be assigned IP's.

Set one PC to

```
IP:     192.168.1.1  
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
```

Set the other PC to

```
IP:     192.168.1.2  
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
```

Then you can ping each other with cmd.exe to check if they can communicate with each other. How to do it and how it looks is like this:

```
C:\Users\Mark>ping 192.168.1.144

Pinging 192.168.1.144 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.144: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.144: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.144: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.144: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.144:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\Mark>
```

Granted, I'm using Windows 7, but it's the same thing.

If both PC's ports do not light up, then none of the PC's have [MDI/MDIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-MDIX) as a feature on their Ethernet port and you will need what is called a [crossover cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable).